# SpringMVC GetJdbcTemplate() getting value from query

Tags: sql, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a function and i would like to extract the vaue from the query i used the getJdbcTemplate and i extract the vaue by passing a string query and an object then accessing the value from the object. I would like to access the value when you actually pass a string. My code is :

Here i use Map but i am not passing an object Map results = getJdbcTemplate().queryForMap(sql, userName) and userName is a String. I would have to use Map but how is this written.

```
public boolean OfficerExist(Officers officer){


    try{

        logger.debug("About to check if officers existing");

        String sql = "SELECT userName FROM crimetrack.tblofficers WHERE userName = ?";

        logger.info("User Name Found 1");

        * Map<String, Object> results = getJdbcTemplate().queryForMap(sql, userName);

        logger.info("User Name Found 2");

        String dbUserName = (String)results.get("userName");

        logger.info("Checking if officers exist "+sql);

        if (dbUserName.equals(userName)) {

            logger.info("User Name Exists");
            return true;

        }else{
            logger.info("User Name Does NOT Exists");
            return false;
        }
        logger.info("User Name Found 3");

        return true;

    }catch(Exception e){

        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking for and/or intending to do. But what you have above will neither compile nor is it appropriate for a simple "does the officer exist" query. Take a look here for some examples of JdbcTemplate usage: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/

Comment: I am trying to check the database to see if the username exist.  I execute the query and extract the value returned from the query. Once I extract the value I can then do something or if it doesn't do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to try is instead of a Map, maybe try just querying for Object since you know you're just querying for the username.

i.e.

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject("select username...", String.class, userName)


public String findCustomerNameById(int custId){

String sql = "SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID = ?";

String name = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
        sql, new Object[] { custId }, String.class);

return name;
```

}